# will <selectKey> generate new id for each insert in MyBatis?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis

```
<insert id="insertIntoScheduleReportUserLink" parameterType="com.mypackage.model.ScheduleReport">

<selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="java.lang.Integer" order="BEFORE">
  select NEXTVAL('schedule_report_user_link_sequence')
</selectKey>

  INSERT INTO schedule_report_user_link(
  id, schedule_report_detail_id, to_user_id)
<foreach collection="selectedUsers" item="user" separator=",">
  VALUES (#{id}, #{scheduleReportDetail.id}, #{user.id})
</foreach>;

</insert>
```

Here I am using for each loop to multiple insert. I need to know if selectKey generate new id for each insert?

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The loop is running  only of the insert section not on the  key generation part.

So its seems the key will be generated once.

Don't depend on hypothesis run for a little data and see it for your self.

Comment: better approach for what.? generating the id every time.?